# HTML form HTTP post does not pass any parameters for certain mobile browsers

Tags: html, servlets, post, mobile-browser

I have an HTML form that uses 'POST' to send parameters to a servlet. When I use a computer the form works for both 'GET' and 'POST' methods. However, on certain mobile phones there are no parameters passed to the servlet when using 'POST'. It does work on mobile phones when using the 'GET' method.

I have tested it on an iPhone 5C (iOS7), iPhone 4 (iOS 6), Samsung Galaxy S3 (Android 4.4.2), Samsung Galaxy S4 (Android 4.4.2), and LG G2 (Android 4.4.2).

It works unreliably when using the Google Chrome mobile browser, but not at all when using the default browser installed. Does anyone know how to make it work for the native browsers?

Thanks!

Below is the code for a simplified version of the error. The form posts to the servlet that prints to the browser all parameters. It is hosted on an Amazon Web Services Elastic Beanstalk running Tomcat 8 Java 8.

The deployed example can also be viewed here:
http://centum2-env-bc2wqa62ib.elasticbeanstalk.com/

On mobile browsers, only the word "Parameters" is printed to the browser.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="./Test" method="post">
        First name: <input type="text" name="firstname"> 
        Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname"> 
        <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Test.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Enumeration;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class Test
 */
@WebServlet("/Test")
public class Test extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public Test() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        out.write("Parameters\n");
        Enumeration<String> parameterNames = request.getParameterNames();

        while (parameterNames.hasMoreElements()) {

            String paramName = parameterNames.nextElement();
            out.write(paramName);
            out.write("\n");

            String[] paramValues = request.getParameterValues(paramName);
            for (int i = 0; i < paramValues.length; i++) {
                String paramValue = paramValues[i];
                out.write("\t" + paramValue);
                out.write("\n");
            }

        }

        out.close();
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        out.write("Parameters\n");
        Enumeration<String> parameterNames = request.getParameterNames();

        while (parameterNames.hasMoreElements()) {

            String paramName = parameterNames.nextElement();
            out.write(paramName);
            out.write("\n");

            String[] paramValues = request.getParameterValues(paramName);
            for (int i = 0; i < paramValues.length; i++) {
                String paramValue = paramValues[i];
                out.write("\t" + paramValue);
                out.write("\n");
            }

        }

        out.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: I was able to reproduce the problem even with my desktop browser. First try works ok. Second try parameters are not printed out. Third try I get 500 exception. It seems it's a bug with Tomcat as I've read about this some time ago.

Comment: I suggest you be more specific in your code and use something like this: request.getParameter("firstname");

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I am printing all parameters just for the example. In the project that I am encountering the problem, I am using request.getParameter("firstname") and it evaluates to null. Printing all parameters is an easy way to test it. Do you have any idea where you may have read about something like this so I can do further research on it?